# How to print specific words from a file

Tags: awk

I have  a file which is like this

```
user:[dgalanos] rid:[0xa35]
user:[roleary] rid:[0xa36]
user:[smorgan] rid:[0xa37]
```

How can i print only the usernames like this

```
dgalanos
roleary
smorgan
```

I tried

```bsh
cat users.txt | awk -F  ':' '{print $2 > "users3.out"}'
```

But it did not give me the correct result i expected.

Comment: don't use [awk redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html) in `awk '{print $2 > "users3.out"}' input` when you don't needed and you actually wanted a shell redirection `awk '{print $2}' input > users3.out `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple way is to modify your command as follows:

`awk -F '[' '{print $2}' users.txt | awk -F ']' '{print $1}' > users3.out`

- I'm using two piped `awk` to catch at first what is after the `[` and then what is after the `]`. The delimiter are you interested in is not the semiclon, but the brackets.
- Piping `|` means that the output of the first command is used as input of the second command. The second `awk` does not work if you use it alone, but it gets some sense only if you pipe it to the first command.
- When piping, you don't have to repeat the input file: for this reason in the second `awk` there is no repetition of the input file `users.txt`. If you are curious to use the second `awk` alone, write: `awk -F ']' '{print $1}' users.txt`
- You don't need to redirect `cat` output to `awk` because `awk` can accept files as input
- Your redirection to an output file must not be inside the `awk` command, but at the end of the full command.

If you want to see the results in the terminal but not in a file, you can remove the part from `>`

There is a [more elegant way](https://askubuntu.com/a/1392824/1037999) to get the data without piping two `awk` commands but defining the two brackets as delimiters:

`awk -F '[][]' '{print $2}' users.txt > users3.out`

Comment: The command give desired result. However can you explain why the second print command did not print anything. awk -F '[' '{print $2}' users.txt | awk -F ']' '{print $1}'  . Is it something like AND statement. it prints only if both conditions before/after the pipe satisfied.

Comment: check my edited answer, it should clear your doubts.

Answer (score 1):

If you set a  colon as your field separator, the line

```
user:[dgalanos] rid:[0xa35]
```

will be split to

```
user
[dgalanos] rid
[0xa35]
```

I guess you want to split at either colon ***or*** space, then remove the brackets:

Also, `awk` defaults to read from a file, no need for `cat`:

```
awk -F  '[: ]' '{gsub(/[][]/,"",$2); print $2}' users.txt > users3.out
```

---

Or you use the brackets as field separator:

```
awk -F  '[][]' '{print $2}' users.txt > users3.out
```

---

Anyways, for such task, I'd prefer `grep`:

```
grep -Po 'user:\[\K[^]]*' users.txt > users3.out
```