# How to remove specific character from file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a file like this.

```
[Guest]
[AAD_987d7f2f57d2]
[mhope]
[SABatchJobs]
[svc-ata]
[svc-bexec]
[svc-netapp]
[dgalanos]
[roleary]
[smorgan]
```

How to remove the '[' and ']' from the file so i can get the output as below

```
Guest
AAD_987d7f2f57d2
mhope
SABatchJobs
svc-ata
svc-bexec
svc-netapp
dgalanos
roleary
smorgan
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sed`:

```
sed 's/[][]//g' file
```

- The `sed` command is `s/pattern/replacement/modifiers`, meaning substitute pattern with replacement. `g` modifier means **g**lobally, otherwise only the first match will be replaced.
- `[...]` is a character class, so any character inside the brackets match.
- `]` closes the character class unless its at first place inside. As we want to include that in our character class, we place it first.
- Replacement is empty in our case.
- Use `sed -i '...'` to edit your file in place.

---

You can also use `grep -P` like I already suggested in your [other question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1392824/631600):

```
grep -Po '\[\K[^]]*' file
```

Comment: I was ready to suggest `sed 's/\[\(.*\)\]/\1/' file`, but your answer is more readable and elegant than mine :-)

Comment: @tcprks if you are interested in applying the modification directly on the file (i.e. overwriting it), you can add a `-i` before `file` (this is true only for the `sed` part of the solution.

Comment: thanks, added that suggestion to my notes :-)

Answer (score 3):

The 'standard' utility to remove specific characters is `tr`:

```
NAME
       tr - translate or delete characters

SYNOPSIS
       tr [OPTION]... SET1 [SET2]

DESCRIPTION
       Translate, squeeze, and/or delete characters from standard input, writ‐
       ing to standard output.
```

So for example

```
tr -d '][' < file
```

Unlike GNU sed, tr only reads from and writes to standard streams; however you can simulate "in place" editing using a temporary file:

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
tr -d '][' < file > "$tmpfile" && mv "$tmpfile" file
```

or with the `sponge` command from package `moreutils`:

```
tr -d '][' < file | sponge file
```

---

You could also use `awk` - for example by splitting lines of the file into *fields* separated by `]` and `[` and printing only the second:

```
awk -F '[][]' '{print $2}' file
```

You can use the same tmpfile trick to simulate "in place" editing, or with GNU awk (aka gawk), use the `inplace` module:

```
gawk -i inplace -F '[][]' '{print $2}' file
```